# Shallow copy of a hashset

Tags: c#, collections, union, traversal, shallow-copy

Whats the best way of doing it?

```
var set2 = new HashSet<reference_type>();
```

Traverse the set with a foreach like this.

```
foreach (var n in set)
    set2.Add(n);
```

Or use something like union like this.

```
set2 = set.UnionWith(set); // all the elements
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the constructor:

```
HashSet<type> set2 = new HashSet<type>(set1);
```

Personally I wish LINQ to Objects had a `ToHashSet` extension method as it does for `List` and `Dictionary`. It's easy to create your own of course:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    return new HashSet<T>(source);
}
```

(With an other overload for a custom equality comparer.)

This makes it easy to create sets of an anonymous type.

Comment: Just an update: LINQ now has a ToHashSet extension method.

Answer (score 19):

Best is subjective, but I'd do it as follows:

```
set2 = new HashSet<type>(set);
```

Or even better:

```
set2 = new HashSet<type>(set, set.Comparer);
```

which ensures you're using the same equality comparer as the original HashSet. For example if the original was a case-insensitive `HashSet<string>`, your new one will also be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably the easiest and best:

```
HashSet<int> s = new HashSet<int>{1,2,3};

HashSet<int> t = new HashSet<int>(s);
```

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

```
HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

> Initializes a new instance of the HashSet class that uses the
>   default equality comparer for the set type, contains elements copied
>   from the specified collection, and has sufficient capacity to
>   accommodate the number of elements copied.